# Using javascript to call external programs (Eg: a C program)

Tags: javascript, html, c, linux, web

I have a web page. I would like to include javascript in the webpage such that on a particular action, the javascript will call an external program, like a C applet program, on my machine. Is it possible to call an external C program using Javascript either directly or through command line?

Comment: on internet explorer you can use ActiveX object, but the user will be warned about the danger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. It's a browser security issue. Client-side JavaScript cannot acces things outside the browser.

Comment: is not a issue, it's a feature!

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it for other users as maxedison explained.

However you can install something called a `network.protocol-handler` in the browser, javascript can trigger that, and that can run whatever you want.

For example in firefox create the key `network.protocol-handler.app.foo` and set the value to the executable you want to run. If you go to `foo://blah` then the executable will run with the value `blah` as a parameter.

Of course you can't do this to someone else's machine, but you can to your own.

Answer (score 1):

See Google's Native Client SDK : http://code.google.com/chrome/nativeclient/

Answer (score 0):

use window.external.c_function ... but you need to see how to compile you C code...  we are doing something like this in one of our project ... and it is working like charm ...